# Is this indicative of just needing a wheel alignement or something more serious?

Tags: ford, alignment, accident

I hit a guardrail going ~25-30mph. The impact was on the front drivers side right under the headlight area. The bumper is a little loose and has a few scratches but has no cracks or breaks. After the accident, the steering wheel is off center meaning to drive straight the ford symbol on the steering wheel is crooked. Th  car pulls hard to the right and turning the wheel all the way to the right has some clunking noises.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

That's definitely more than a wheel alignment.  Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Get it fixed before you drive it anymore, it is dangerous and will destroy your tires. Likely bent something.